# Best way to use match case for integers in Python

Tags: python

What is the best way to check whether something is an integer in Python 3.10+, regardless if it is a native int, or numpy int8, int32, int64 etc. ?

```
import numpy as np

def func(token):
    match token:
        case int():
            print('integer')
        case str():
            print('string')
    print('failed')


func('a')
>>> string

func(1)
>>> integer

func(np.int64(1))
>>> failed  # this should return True
```

I found the answer, but someone closed the question...

```
import numpy as np

def func(token):
    match token:
        case int() | np.int8() | np.int32() | np.int64() | np.uint8() | np.uint32() | np.uint64():
            return 'integer'
        case np.int64():
            return 'integer64'
        case str():
            return 'string'
    return 'failed'
```

Comment: Can you use `isinstance(token, int)`?

Comment: That would require the idea of "integerness" to be something Python specifically associates with all the relevant types, which it does not. There is no common protocol that binds those types together.

Comment: The linked answer does not use match and case.

Comment: it doesn't, but you should be able tot apply the information their to your use-case. You are going to probably have to use a guard and `isinstance(n, (int, np.integer))`. Note, this only will apply to numpy integer type and the built-in int. There is no generic "int-ness" in the language. And the numeric tower never took off and seems to have been mostly abandoned

Comment: That does not work with match/case.

Comment: @Soren Match statements are an exciting new feature, but that doesn't mean that they solve all problems better than the old features. As said above, a match statement isn't a good tool for this job, because there's no pattern that you can use to check for "intness". There are good non-pattern-matching tools that you can use, which are described in the duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, I am basically just trying out this new feature. I guess there are better ways.